# angularjs - Change the order of a list with update of the other list entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a Key/Value List with 3 Entries, e.g.

0, Value1

1, Value2

2, Value3

3, Value4

If I change 2 to 0, the entry with index 2 should slip to the position 0 and the additional elements slip around a position to the back.

eg from 0-1-2-3 will then be 2-0-1-3

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="row-sort" ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in selectList">
    <select class="row-select">
      <option ng-repeat="(key2, value2) in selectList" value={{key2}} ng-selected="key1 == key2">{{key2}}</option>
    </select>
    <span class="row-label">{{value1.name}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.selectList = [{
    idx: 0,
    name: 'Value1'
  }, {
    idx: 1,
    name: 'Value2'
  }, {
    idx: 2,
    name: 'Value3'
  }, {
    idx: 3,
    name: 'Value4'
  }]
}
```

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/slopdel/7r15jou0/6/)

EDIT 1: It sould work like the jQuery Sortable Plugin, but only with Select-Boxes ... 
[Jquery Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/)

Anyone a idea how getting this work properly and correct with AngularJS?

Its required for Angular UI Grid (Reorder Columns)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to your list `selected` key to bind it to `ng-model`s for select and use `orderBy`:

```
$scope.selectList = [{
    idx: 0,
    selected: '0',
    name: 'Value1'
  }, {
    idx: 1,
    selected: '1',
    name: 'Value2'
  }, {
    idx: 2,
    selected: '2',
    name: 'Value3'
  }, {
    idx: 3,
    selected: '3',
    name: 'Value4'
  }];
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="row-sort" ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in selectList | orderBy : 'selected'">
    <select class="row-select" ng-model="value1.selected">
      <option ng-repeat="(key2, value2) in selectList" 
              value={{key2}}>{{key2}}</option>
    </select>
    <span class="row-label">{{value1.name}}</span>
  </div>
```

**EDIT**

You can write watcher and replace positions for your items:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
        return $scope.selectList;
    },
   function (newVal, oldVal) {

     var selectedItemId;
     var selected;
      angular.forEach($scope.selectList, function(item){
          if(item.idx !== parseInt(item.selected)){
            selectedItemId = item.idx;
            selected = item.selected;            
            }         
      });

      angular.forEach($scope.selectList, function(item){
          if(item.selected === selected){
            item.selected = ''+selectedItemId;
            item.idx = selectedItemId;
            selectedItemId = undefined;
            selected = undefined;
            }   

            if(item.idx !== parseInt(item.selected)){
              item.idx = parseInt(item.selected);
            }
      });      
    },true);
```

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ftr4x2ru/)</kbd>

Comment: Hello Maxim, thanks for your answer. Yes i need unique ids so i think this is not working for me, tried ng-changed already with own function behind, but the event get not fired ...

Comment: @slopsucker I added new demo that looks like what you want.